# Favicon doesn't display without www

Tags: html, favicon

I put `favicon.ico` to my www catalog. If I type `http://www.mypageaddress.com` the icon is displayed, but if I type `http://mypageaddress.com` without www, the icon doesn't display.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try cleaning your cache in your browser
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201406/cannot-get-favicon-ico-to-display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

upload a favicon.ico in your root dir and don't worry about explicitly defining it in the HTML.

Comment: And here's the problem. Favicon.ico is in a root catalog and not displaying without www in the address.

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue, I wouldn't stress it at all

Comment: I think it's not a browser issue. Check http://mapagdz.pl and http://www.mapagdz.pl

Comment: could be the settings on your local server.  I wouldn't stress it especially if this site is going to be on a shared server.  It's no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

then u must change it to:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://ex.com/favicon.png"/>
```

and make sure of using "http://ex.com/ insted of "http://www.ex.com/

Comment: I need to have the icon on 'http://(...)' and 'http://www.(...)' as well. And don't want to paste any additional code. It should works by putting favicon.ico to root dir. But why it doesn't?

Comment: i believe this has to do with the browser i just tried it for you and it worked will with no pro

Comment: Yes, I checked again and it works. Maybe my local server needed a refresh or something like that.